# How to measure change in degrees per second, given force applied at a certain angle?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

Example: a rectangular spaceship weights 10.000kg, and has a lenght of 20 meters. A force of 1.000 newtons is applied at a 90° angle and 9 meters away from center of mass. What will be the change in degrees per second?

Comment: If it is rectangular it must have a height value also. Otherwise it is rod shaped with only length.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ja72 yes but does the height matter for the calculations? I said lenght so ppl would know it wasn't an irregular shape, Im not sure if it matters either tho

Comment: @RealAnyOne - The MMOI of a rectangular shape is $$I = \frac{m}{12} \left( \ell^2 + h^2 \right)$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Calculate the *Mass Moment of Inertia* about the center of mass. $$ I = \frac{m}{12} \ell^2 \; \; \; \; \rightarrow \mbox{slender rod of mass $m$ and length $\ell$} $$
2. Calculate the net torque about the center of mass $$ \tau = d\,F \sin \theta  \; \; \; \; \rightarrow \mbox{force $F$ at distance $d$ at angle $\theta$ }$$
3. Apply the planar equations of motion $$ \begin{aligned}
   F & = m a_y \\ \tau &= I \alpha \end{aligned} \; \; \; \; \rightarrow \mbox{vertical acceleration $a_y$, rotational acceleration $\alpha$} $$

Comment: If you don't mind explaining me a few things, why is MMOI needed and not just total mass? Why is mass divided by 12? Why there's 2 different equations for T? What value does rotational acceleration have? And why is it F = ma * y (and not x for example)

Comment: MMOI is used to define angular momentum and change in angular momentum is due to torque. Total mass is only needed to describe the motion of the center of mass only. Rotation about the center of mass is due to MMOI.

Comment: There is only one equation for equipollent torque. In 3d it is $\tau = r \times F$ where $\times$ is the vector cross product. The planar version of this is the product of the perpendicular projection $(d \sin \theta)$ and the force $F$.

Comment: $a_y$ is the acceleration along the _y_-axis. It is not $F = m a y$, but $F=m a$ along a specific direction.

Comment: The units of rotational velocity is in $\mbox{radians per second}$ and hence acceleration is $\mbox{(radians per second) per second}$.

Answer (score -1):

Is the force constantly pushing at that $90^\circ$? If so, just use rotational kinematics (and some more info, like how long the force is acting or through what angle you are moving through) to find the angular frequencey $\omega$, which is in radians per second. Then convert it to degrees per second: $\omega(\frac{180^\circ}{\pi})=degrees/second$